# automating html build with gruntjs

Tags: node.js, gulp, gruntjs

I am developing a pretty standard web app with the following directory structure

```
/ app ⊢ index.html
        ⊢ / js
            ⊢ app.min.js
        ⊢ / css
            ⊢ app.min.css
        ⊢ / dev
            ⊢ index.html
            ⊢ / js
                ⊢ app1.js
                ⊢ app2.js
            ⊢ / css
                ⊢ app1.css
                ⊢ app2.css
```

A `gruntjs` script uglifies, concats and minifies the `/dev/js/*.js` and `/dev/css/*.css` files and writes them to the top-level folders, ready to be included in the `/index.html`. I can't figure out how to automatically process the `/dev/index.html` as well so that too gets updated with all the latest changes and written out to the root level `/index.html`. What is the simplest way to automate this?

I found https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-replace for `gulpjs`, but I have not been able to find something similar for `gruntjs`

**Update:** I have decided to move from `gruntjs` to `gulpjs` as it seems to me to be better documented.

**Update2:** see answer below

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else is stuck with this problem, here is how I solved it with `gulpjs`

```js
const { parallel, src, dest } = require('gulp');

const htmlreplace = require('gulp-html-replace');
const cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const terser = require('gulp-terser');

const htmldest = '.';
const cssdest = htmldest + '/css';
const jsdest = htmldest + '/js';

const finalcss = 'app.min.css';
const finaljs = 'app.min.js';

function docss() {
    return src('dev/css/*.css')
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(concat(finalcss))
        .pipe(dest(cssdest));
}

function dohtml() {
    return src('dev/index.html')
        .pipe(htmlreplace({
            'css': `css/${finalcss}`,
            'js': `js/${finaljs}`
        }))
        .pipe(dest(htmldest));
}

function dojs(){
  return src('dev/js/*.js')
    .pipe(terser())
    .pipe(concat(finaljs))
    .pipe(dest(jsdest));
}

exports.default = parallel(docss, dohtml, dojs);
```